# Why dashboard route is not accessible to me even if I am logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-native, redux

I am using private route in my app to access dashboard. if I am not logged in it worked correctly and redirect me to the sign in page. but even if I am logged in it does not gives access to dashboard. Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './containers/Home';
import Login from './containers/Login';
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          
 
          </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
       if (!auth.isAuthenticated) {
         return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        
      } else {
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }
    }}
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

And if I am logged in on react redux tool my states are these [image: State]

I noticed even if isAuthanticated becomes true after login but **else** part of privateRoutes.js never called